# How to replace a text from a dynamic table into a picture

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On my site I have a scoreboard that receives it's info from a other website, so the content is dynamic.
I am trying to replace parts of the content of a table with pictures. So that instead of the 3 letterword of a club the logo appears. But my knowledge of CSS an Jquery is not large enough.
Can someone help my with the CSS or other html language parts?

This is the content that generates the table:

```html
<style>
  table,
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #c71b1b
  }
  
  th,
  td1 {
    padding: 1px;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #c71b1b
  }
</style>


<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
          <h1>MANNEN</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=14%>DATUM</td>
        <td width=13%>UUR</td>
        <td width=12%>THUIS</td>
        <td width=12%>UIT</td>
        <td width=49%>SCORE</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-men">
          <p><img src="//www.pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
          <h1>VROUWEN</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=14%>DATUM</td>
        <td width=13%>UUR</td>
        <td width=12%>THUIS</td>
        <td width=12%>UIT</td>
        <td width=49%>SCORE</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table cellspacing="20">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-women">
          <p><img src="//www.pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Include JS script to do the job, block definition(s) and main function call -->
<script src="//stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/js/pb-update-ex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--//--><![CDATA[// ><!--


  blockdefs = [{
      leagueid: 'bel/29/2022',
      blocktype: 'team-games',
      target: 'block-main-men',
      teamid: '413'
    },
    {
      leagueid: 'bel/30/2022',
      blocktype: 'team-games',
      target: 'block-main-women',
      teamid: '207'
    }
  ];

  PBShowBlocks(blockdefs);


  //--><!]]>
</script>
<!-- End -->
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `TR > DIV` is invalid markup. Also your tables headings do not align. Use `<thead>`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see how the code is supposed to work now. See edited code below.

---

1. You're not including the *src* tags correctly. In every script and image tag, you included something like "//google.com". That's not a valid URL. Usually, if you're fetching from another URL, you put something like `src="https://google.com/"`
2. The JS file you linked has an error in it. You can see it if you open the console. It's not using the proper path for the css file. It's saying the path for the css file *pb-blocks.css* is at `stats.pointbench.com/css/pb-blocks.css` but I'd bet it's actually at, following the same path structure as the JS file, `stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/css/pb-blocks.css` https://stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/css/pb-blocks.css

   If you have access to that server, you can fix it there, but if not, I'll put a fix at the end.

---

Okay since the JS file is broken, just go to the url for the JS file and copy and paste the content and put it in your public/assets route.

Ctrl-F and find every instance of `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);` On the line above it, you'll see `fileref.setAttribute("href", gUpdateDomain + "pointbench/css/pb-blocks.css");` Replace it with this line: `fileref.setAttribute("href", "https://stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/css/pb-blocks.css");`
There should be two instances of this.

Also, your table structure is invalid. Below is the proper table structure

```
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Overall, your code just needs a little touch up to make it look pretty. I removed the unnecessary elements and the closing tags with no open tags. See code below:

```
<style>
  table, td, th {  
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
  }

 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
 }

 th, td {
    padding: 1px;
 }

 th{
    background-color: #c71b1b
 }

 th, td1 {
    padding: 1px;
 }

 th{
    background-color: #c71b1b
 }

</style>


<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <thead>
            <tr colspan="5">
                <th><h1>MANNEN</h1></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width=14%>DATUM</td>
              <td width=13%>UUR</td>
              <td width=12%>THUIS</td>
              <td width=12%>UIT</td>
              <td width=49%>SCORE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-men">
                  <p><img src="https://pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="20">
        <thead colspan="5">
            <th colspan="5">
                <tr><h1>VROUWEN</h1></tr>
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td width=14%>DATUM</td>
              <td width=13%>UUR</td>
              <td width=12%>THUIS</td>
              <td width=12%>UIT</td>
              <td width=49%>SCORE</td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-women">
                  <p><img src="https://pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="https://stats.pointbench.com/pointbench/js/pb-update-ex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

blockdefs =
[
{
  leagueid: 'bel/29/2022',
  blocktype: 'team-games',
  target: 'block-main-men',
  teamid: '413'
},
{
  leagueid: 'bel/30/2022',
  blocktype: 'team-games',
  target: 'block-main-women',
  teamid: '207'
}
];

PBShowBlocks( blockdefs );


</script>
```

---

As for your question, replacing team initials with a team logo is possible and doable. But to do this, you need to have the team logos stored somewhere, or fetch them from a server using API. Assuming there's only a couple of team logos, you can easily download them all and store them, then replace the initials with a logo.

For this example I'm gonna use a URL of a logo from the internet.

Say we have a table like the one you have, I don't know which cell in your table is a team name. But let's assume it's the 2nd and 3rd cell in every row.

I'd write some code like this:

```
<table cellspacing="20">
    <thead>
        <th colspan="5">
            <tr><h1>MANNEN</h1></tr>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mensteam">
        <tr>
          <td width=14%>DATUM</td>
          <td width=13%>RM</td>
          <td width=12%>FCB</td>
          <td width=12%>UIT</td>
          <td width=49%>SCORE</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

    function setLogo(teaminitials) {
        switch(teaminitials)
        {
            case "RM": 
                var src = "https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/real-madrid-logo-png/real-madrid-logo-large-images-3.png";
                break;
            case "FCB":
                var src = "https://pngimg.com/uploads/poop/poop_PNG52.png";
                break;
        }
        return src;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        const menTable = $('#mensteam');
        $('#mensteam tr').each(function(){
            //first team
            var teamName = $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)');
            var logo = setLogo(teamName.text());
            teamName.text("");
            teamName.prepend('<img style="max-width: 10%;" src="' + logo + '" >');

            //second team
            var teamName2 = $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)');
            var logo2 = setLogo(teamName2.text());
            teamName2.text("");
            teamName2.prepend('<img style="max-width: 10%;" src="' + logo2 + '" >');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Before**
[image: Table Before]

**After**
[image: Table After]

Answer (score 0):

Your table stucture doesn't follow the expected pattern. Maybe the browser is also rewriting the tags to match the correct hierarchy, what "breaks" the selector logic inside the image replacer function.

Try:

```html
<table cellspacing="20">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>       
            <div class="pb-dynamic" id="block-main-women">
               <p><img src="//www.pointbench.com/pointbench/img/pb-loading-1.gif" /></p>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, the image url is not correct (you are missing the http: or https: before the //)